# Does TypeScript have a NaN type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, types

Does TypeScript have a NaN type that I could declare for a variable?

For example, if I was to create a variable like this:

```
const number: number = parseInt('123', 10);
```

Could I change it to be more accurate, like so:

```
const number: number | NaN = parseInt('123', 10);
```

Basically I want to know if I can declare a variable as a NaN type (not undefined or null). The above snippet doesn't work in TypeScript and I can't find it listed in either the Basic or Advanced Types within TypeScript's guides.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no `NaN` type in Typescript. There is [a proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682) for this on GitHub but there is no timeline for implementation. Consider upvoting the issue if you want to see this feature in Typescript.

Comment: Oh cool! I definitely want to see this feature, thank you

Comment: I note that `NaN` is still not really a separate _type_ (as far as JavaScript is concerned) but this is more a case of using a type-system to model constraints on values - not that there's anything wrong with that, but many people would argue that a preconditions/postconditions system (aka _code-contracts_) would be more useful for problems like these - with the benefit of also allowing for runtime assertions, something that TypeScript's language designers outright refuse to support.

Comment: EcmaScript doesn't really matter. In TS we can define a type as `("NaN"|"Infinity"|"-Infinity")` but those are strings. So why not the same with numbers? The problem is that `NaN as const` doesn't have a type yet. But it works with strings: `const n : 'NaN' = 'NaN' as const;`