# @typescript-eslint strict-boolean-expressions check for falsy value

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I recently had an issue regarding a ternary checking a `number | undefined` var for `undefined`, but due to my lack of attention when writing the code, when the number was 0, it wrongly accused it being a undefined value.

Then, I found about about the [strict-boolean-expressions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md) ESLint rule.

Looks very useful and safe, but, given this example:

```js
const text: string | undefined = stringOrUndefined1 || stringOrUndefined2 || undefined; // the strings can be empty
if (!text) // I was doing it this way to check if the value was falsy. With the new rule, it complains.
  return;
if (text === undefined || text === '') // This works, but is 4x the length of the one above. I don't want to write the var name more than once
if (!!text == false) // "Unexpected nullable string value in conditional. Please handle the nullish/empty cases explicitly."
if (!!!text) // Same warn as above
```

Is there any way to quickly and nicely check if the value is falsy without the lengthy second conditional, and without disabling the rule, even just for the specific line?

I know that it's possible to disable just for nullable strings, but this question also applies for numbers, the rule that I want to keep for safety reasons.

Comment: The purpose of the strict-boolean-expressions rule is to warn on implicit conversions to boolean; "truthy" or "falsy" only matter when you do want these implicit conversions. `!!text` requires an implicit conversion to boolean for the first `!` that is applied; it is not clear what circumstances you want the warning and what circumstances you don't.

Comment: As the answers here are valid, they really aren't good enough to be used without commenting the code to explain why they are being used. The best option I think it would be, to check for falsy values, is simply and logically `text == false` as JS allows. However, there is an already issued bug on Typescript that doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 17):

You could try using the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) like this:

```
if (!(text ?? '')) {}
```

`text ?? ''` evaluates to `''` if it is `undefined` and `text` otherwise.

This is equivalent to the following:

```
if (!(text !== null && text !== undefined ? text : '')) {}
```

Comment: This is likely the best answer for this particular case. It means your code is clear and explicit. Using the `??` operator makes your conditional clearly mean "I am handling the nullish case exactly the same as the empty string case".

Comment: The `strict-boolean-types` rule *"Forbids usage of non-boolean types in expressions where a boolean is expected"*, so it should complain about the expression `!(text ?? '')` since `text ?? ''` is of type `string`, not `boolean`.

Comment: @kaya3 By default, the [`allowString`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md#allowstring) option is `true`, which allows the use of strings in boolean expressions. This is safe because there is only one falsy value (`''`).

Comment: I see. At least, if that option is disabled, you could write `(text ?? '') != ''` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned - the point of `strict-boolean-expressions` is to help ensure you are explicitly handling each case so that you don't accidentally let certain cases slip through.

@cherryblossom's answer is one way to do it concisely and clearly - it shows you are intentionally handling the nullish and empty string cases the same way.

If your project is okay with doing loose checks on nullish strings - you can reconfigure the rule as appropriate: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md#allownullablestring

---

As an aside - personally I don't see the problem with just typing the extra few characters in the check. The clear and explicit handling is good for your codebase, and ultimately it's only a handful of extra keystrokes.

Most IDEs (like VSCode) have the ability to add templated snippets if you're so inclined to save keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the "truthiness" of a value despite having `strict-boolean-expressions` enabled, you could define helper functions for the purpose:

```
type Falsy = 0 | '' | false | null | undefined

function truthy<T>(x: T): x is Exclude<T, Falsy> {
    return !!(x as any);
}

function falsy<T>(x: T): x is T & Falsy {
    return !(x as any);
}
```

Then you can write `if(truthy(str)) { ... }` or `if(falsy(str)) { ... }` where you want to use those tests.

Note that the definition of the `Falsy` type here is incomplete; for example when `T` is `number` then `falsy` will narrow `x` to the literal type `0` when `NaN` is also a possible falsy value. Unfortunately, there is no way around this since [Typescript has no NaN literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999696/does-typescript-have-a-nan-type); this will only be a problem if you do expect NaN values in your code.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good solution. The point of the `strict-boolean-expressions` rule is to ensure that your checks are performed strictly and explicitly. Defining these functions is just working around the rule - at that point you might as well either allow nullable strings (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md#allownullablestring) or just turn off the rule

Comment: @BradZacher I think `if(truthy(str))` is quite explicit about what it does, don't you?

Comment: There is one obvious problem I can see: these functions do not understand types, meaning that they will not correctly refine variables (example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gDwFz0xgEsUBzeAH3hQFcIIBuAKCdElgQDMaUwMjU8DDBoYAFgE8AFLFL4oKCQEp8AIyRIIIBcyZFO8KdiXwA3k3iX4Aems54RNNVQBaWvUdiLV7ADotZOLMAL4s+obCopJGSibmVjZ2AKLYAA7gGCDA8EkwMEgw8KrgUDRoCNgOTu4Qnt6WfgGkQUyhQA)

Comment: I don't personally think this is clear. `truthy(str)` could mean any number of things, one of which is "I am explicitly treating null and empty string as false". It's still ambiguous whether or not you are explicitly handling the cases or if you were just lazy.

Each line of code is written once, however it will be read many, many times.
Because of this, you should optimise code for clarity, explicitness and readability above all things.

To clarify: IMO it's always better to use 10 extra keystrokes and be clear and explicit, than save 10 and be ambiguous.

Comment: The Javascript language defines which values are truthy and which are falsy - it would be misleading for functions with these names to do anything else. It is hard to imagine how one could be more explicit about testing whether a value is truthy, than by calling a function whose name says that this is what it tests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: The lack of type narrowing is a good point, so I've edited the answer to support it.

Comment: "It is hard to imagine how one could be more explicit about testing whether a value is truthy" --- By explicitly checking! `x != null && x !== ''` is clearer as there is absolutely no ambiguity. You have clearly and explicitly handled both false cases and nobody can misread this as "they didn't understand the lint error", "they hacked around the linter", or "maybe they didn't realise `''` was falsy". Which is exactly what you want from code - clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Your proposal is included in the question as an example of something that is not what the OP is looking for: *"This works, but is 4x the length of the one above. I don't want to write the var name more than once"*. If the name `falsy` is not explicit enough for you, though, it would be trivial to rename the function to something more descriptive in your opinion.